# DataTable; Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following line of code,

```
sitetb.Text = sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"].Rows[_selectedindex].Field<string>("SiteName").ToString();
```

This returns the

> *System.NullReferenceException; Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.*

I know why it is returning this exception and thats because there is nothing in that cell.

How do I correctly handle this?

Comment: If you are referring to the `Field` being null, then you must check for null first before calling `ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need to call `.ToString()`**

`.Field<string>("SiteName")` convert to string , you don't need to call tostring again.

```
sitetb.Text = sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"].Rows[_selectedindex].Field<string>("SiteName");
```

if your cell value null then you can't call `ToString` method of null object, that will fail.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(sitesformdataset!=null&&sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"]!=null)
{
sitetb.Text = sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"].Rows[_selectedindex].Field<string>("SiteName").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked for `_selectedindex` != -1 and being in the correct range the correct the code like this:

```
sitetb.Text = (sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"].Rows[_selectedindex].Field<string>("SiteName")?? "").ToString();
```

it is the short writing of this:

```
var cellContetnt = sitesformdataset.Tables["Sites"].Rows[_selectedindex].Field<string>("SiteName");
if(cellCount == null)
    sitetb.Text = "";
else
    sitetb.Text = cellContent.ToString();
```